# How to solve "ValueError: File 'load.xlsx' is already in use." error encountered when use 'abq_ExcelUtilities.excelUtilities.ExcelToAmplitude' method?

Tags: python, excel, abaqus

I'm trying to import a load data from an Excel file to Abaqus Amplitude object by using python script, so that I can automate the preprocess to realize a large number of load conditions. But there is an Error: "ValueError: File 'load.xlsx' is already in use. Close the file before importing the data."

However, I have never opened this Excel file. I have reboot the computer to make sure the file is not opened. This error still appears. Below is what I entered in the Kernel Command Line Interface in Abaqus and the response:

> > > import abq_ExcelUtilities
> > >
> > > abq_ExcelUtilities.excelUtilities.ExcelToAmplitude(inputFileForAmp='load.xlsx',sheetNameForAmp='Sheet1', ampStartCell='A1', ampEndCell='B34972', ampNameStr='Amp-1', amplitudeType=0)
> > >       Importing file "load.xlsx"...
> > >       File "SMAPyaModules\SMAPyaPluginsPy.m\src\abaqus_plugins\excelUtilities\abq_ExcelUtilities\excelUtilities.py", line 465, in ExcelToAmplitude
> > >       File "SMAPyaModules\SMAPyaPluginsPy.m\src\abaqus_plugins\excelUtilities\abq_ExcelUtilities\excelUtilities.py", line 682, in CreateObject
> > >       File "SMAPyaModules\SMAPyaPluginsPy.m\src\abaqus_plugins\excelUtilities\abq_ExcelUtilities\excelUtilities.py", line 512, in ExtractDataFromExcel
> > >       ValueError: File 'load.xlsx'
> > >       is already in use. Close the file before importing the data.

I have no idea where to begin to address this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is module **abq_ExcelUtilities**? If you just want to write Abaqus amplitude from Excel file, there is a plug-in **Excel Utilities**. You can access it from the menubar **Plug-ins > Tools > Excel Utilities**

Comment: The module **abq_ExcelUtilities** must be imported before Excel Utilities can be recognized by abaqus kernel. The plug-in you mentioned is exactly the GUI version of  Excel Utilities. I want to realize this function through the python script. Then I can use a loop block to **automaticly** write  a large number of load.@Tom

Comment: I can import **abq_ExcelUtilities** without any error.   @Yachuan

Comment: Did you mean the excel file **Or** only the abq_ExcelUtilities? I can also import abq_ExcelUtilities without error. The error occurs on the action of importing .xlsx file@Tom

Comment: It doesn't show any error when importing excel file if the absolute path is used.

Comment: I have finished importing data through .csv files. It's easier and faster than Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by **close all software in the Windows tray**. One of the softwares that startup along with Windows may obstructs my script. But when I reboot my PC again to trial out which one caused this trouble, the problem totally disappeared, and never show up.

Thanks to @Tom for his concern! Any good insight is welcomed.